# ChiDist excel function in python

Tags: python, excel, vba, scipy, poisson

I have an excel function that i'm trying to replicate into python but struggling to replicate it. Here's the function (VBA):

```
Function Z(Lambda, conf) As Integer
Application.Volatile
Lambda = Application.Round(Lambda, 3)
Select Case Lambda
Case Is < 400
For i = 0 To 500
'        v = Application.Poisson(i, Lambda, True)
v = Application.ChiDist(2 * Lambda, 2 * i + 2)
    If v >= conf Then
        Z = i
        Exit Function
    End If
  Next
Case Else
    Z = Application.NormInv(conf, Lambda, Sqr(Lambda))
End Select
End Function
```

In Excel if i run `=z(2,95%)`, i get `z=5`

I thought I could use:

```
from scipy import stats
stats.chi2.cdf
```

but not getting far with it.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the function working in python - thanks @Warren Weckesser for the guidance on the chi2.sf.

```
from scipy.stats import norm, chi2

 def z(lamda_calc, prob):

if lamda_calc < 400:
  z_calc = [i for i in range (0,500) if chi2.sf(2 * lamda_calc, 2 * i + 2) >= 
  prob][0]  
else:
  z_calc = int(norm.ppf(prob,lamda_calc,sqrt(lamda_calc)))
return z_calc

print
print ("z:'", z(1.4, 0.98))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`ChiDist` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.ChiDist), (see also [CHIDIST](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/chidist-function-c90d0fbc-5b56-4f5f-ab57-34af1bf6897e)), `ChiDist` returns the right tail of the Χ² distribution.  The corresponding function in SciPy is the `sf` ([survival function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function)) method of `scipy.stats.chi2`.  In your Python code, change `stats.chi2.cdf` to `stats.chi2.sf`.

Comment: Using stats.chi2.sf gives the same result as the .cdf function

Comment: Do you enter `conf` as `95` or `0.95`? Be sure to use `0.95` in the Python code.  Can you include your Python code in the question?